# Passing values from Google Maps Javascript API v3 to Flex Application

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps-api-3

I converted our Google Map application for flash (version 2) to version 3.0 which is a Javascript API. Now I am having problem on how to pass values from the map HTML page to flex application.

Specifically, what I want to do is to pass the coordinates (set of Lat/Lon values) from the map to flex application so that the flex app can save those values in the database. Is there any way to do this?

Note: I am using "flex-iframe-1.4.6.swc" to show the Google Maps.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [flex-iframe FAQ](https://github.com/flex-users/flex-iframe/wiki/FAQ):

> **Communication between Flex and javascript**
>
> I.e. calling back into the Flex app from the page and calling into
>   javascript from the Flex app. The way I implemented this was using
>   FABridge. See the IFrameBridgeTest demo. So it's possible but it's not
>   simple.

Comment: Thanks Gady, I ran across this as well.